# Luxon js get day from week day number

Tags: javascript, luxon

Moment had the option to get the day name based on week number (0 to 6). I see that luxon has day of the week, as number from 1-7 (Monday is 1, Sunday is 7)https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/parsing but I dont know how can I convert the week number to day name?

In moment

```js
moment().day(0).format('ddddd'); // Sunday
```

Comment: 'cccc' or 'EEEE'? https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/formatting ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd have a look at luxon's [Info.weekdays](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#infoweekdays), this will give day names in various formats.

However the day numbering is slightly different to Moment, so you'll have to translate.

```js
const { Info } = luxon;
// moment.js days of week: Sunday: 0 -> Monday: 6
const momentDays = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6];

console.log('Index', 'Long', 'Short');
momentDays.forEach(day => {
    // Luxon day indexes are Monday: 0 -> Sunday 6
    const luxonDay = (day + 6) % 7;
    console.log(day, Info.weekdays('long')[luxonDay], Info.weekdays('short')[luxonDay]);
})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/2.0.2/luxon.min.js" integrity="sha512-frUCURIeB0OKMPgmDEwT3rC4NH2a4gn06N3Iw6T1z0WfrQZd7gNfJFbHrNsZP38PVXOp6nUiFtBqVvmCj+ARhw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: A+ answer... thank you.

In Luxon v3.2.1, `Info.weekdays()` appears to give the following array order that starts with "Monday":

["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]

Answer (score 0):

As of Luxon 3.4.4, you can do DateTime.now().weekdayLong or DateTime.now().weekdayShort https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimeweekday